# Why do I need to Set File Attributes C#?

Tags: c#

Hi I am new to C# and I am reviewing a code I didn't write. The code copies a compressed file from a network location to a local location before it is extracted and then parsed for data. The copy file function is:

```
public static void CopySourceFileToDestinationFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            try
            {
                //copy log from source to local and uncompress it
                File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
                File.SetAttributes(destinationPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errmsg = $"ERROR in function 'CopySourceFileToDestinationFile()': {ex.Message.ToString()}";
                Logger.Error(errmsg);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(errmsg);
            }
        }
```

I see the File.SetAttributes function and looked up it and all it said on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setattributes?view=net-5.0 was telling me what the function is but not why you'd need it.

So I humbly ask, why do I ever need to use this function? Had I written this code from scratch I wouldn't have known the existence of this function, nor it's purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were reviewing that code, what I'd be more curious about is why the original developer put a lying comment above the copy action (it *doesn't* decompress) and why they catch an exception only to log and throw its message (why not the exception type and its stack trace)?

But about the attributes: a file, when written, will get an Archive flag, indicating to backup software that the file should be backed up. Clearing this bit by setting the file's attributes to Normal (i.e. no attributes) will ... probably not be very relevant, unless this file is copied into a directory that will actually be backed up.

It's not very relevant as any decent backup program won't just look at the Archive bit to decide whether to include a file in its backup or not. Clearing this attribute, as well as the rest of the code, reeks like code smell, cargo cult, voodoo programming and whatnot.

Comment: Hmm backup software? How would a backup software know to backup a file? Actually what backup software are you referring to? Do they all depend on Windows to set an archival flag? Is this archival flag set when a file is compressed?

Comment: And its part of a bigger service that has many functions that can create a large log file. I suspect that's why he only passed a message.

Comment: It is what the Archive bit was originally made up for, like 30 years ago. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit. It is AFAIK the only meaningful attribute that can be set by and cleared this way after a File.Copy().